# Grails war command - do not promt for plugin update

Tags: grails, deployment, build, jenkins, war

Here's the situation, I have automated build server, that builds app war and deploys it to local tomcat on every git commit. Now, as part of the project I have custom written plugin, and every time I update plugin version, there is promprt for plugin version update, that stops and eventually breaks the build process (as thread gets destroyed after 'n' seconds).
Now I'm curios is there any way to pass an option to `grails war` command, so it automatically accepts this plugin updates? One of the workarounds would be to pass "y" string as stdin to build script:

```
cat "yyyy" | project-build.sh
```

, but I'm curios if there is such command in `grails war` command, or any other way that grails automatically picks up new version, as this version IS specified in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
  compile ":custom-plugin:1.1.4"
}
```

Still I got question if I want to be update from 1.1.3 to 1.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grails war --non-interactive` will bypass the question and do the update.

`--non-interactive` can be applied to any `grails` command and will automatically choose the default selection for any questions.

Comment: That's the switch I've been searching for! Thanks alot, budy!